# Laravel, Route required parameter is not validating by Form Request Validation

Tags: laravel, validation

I am using laravel 5.4

### routes/web.php [Route]

```
Route::get('/email-confirmation/{token}', ['uses' => 'Components\ConfirmationController@sendEmailConfirmation', 'as' => 'web.email.confirmation']);
```

### Components/ConfirmationController.php [Controller]

```
public function sendEmailConfirmation(EmailConfirmationRequest $request) 
{
dd($request->input('token'));
// ouput is empty
}
```

// I know that, route required parameter is access by passing in it as second parameter

### EmailConfirmationRequest.php [Request]

```
public function rules()
{
    return ['token' => 'required|max:3'];
}
```

URL : /email-confirmation/hello - not validating

So, It cannot validated the `token` parameter in the request.

I am not sure, I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I think it's because you are trying to validate aa route parameter and the dd is truying to access the request parameter : /email-confirmation/{token} is a route parameter. you might want to check this by posting to /email-confirmation/1?token=test and dd($request->all()) in the controller

Comment: you have to decide if you want `token` to be a route parameter or a GET/POST input, in the first case is injected in the action call after the $request argument and you cannot validate it, in the second case is in the `request()->input('token)` and you can validate.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the comments already have said, you are passing the `$token` as a route parameter, not an input value.

To use this route parameter update your method (adding `$token`)

```
public function sendEmailConfirmation(EmailConfirmationRequest $request, $token) 
{
    dd($token);
    // output should be $token value
}
```

If you do want to pass it as an input you can add it as a hidden field in your form.